# What is the equivalent of AWS lambda Layers in Azure provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, webpack, serverless, serverless-framework

**Problem**

I have a project which is standalone **aws serverless** backend which makes use of lambda layers concept to share `node_modules` and other `custom dependencies`.

One of the use case of custom dependencies in my case are having all the common codes like `HTTP_STATUS_CODE` enum and `Api responses util` for status code and sequelize models and services in a folder which is later copied in to `node_modules` and host it to a `s3 bucket`

*folder structure*

```
.
├── customDependencies
│   └── nodejs
│       └── sequelizeORM
│           ├── config
│           ├── migrations
│           ├── models
│           ├── seeders
│           └── services
├── node_modules
└── src
    ├── functions
        ├── func1
        ├── func2
        ├── func3
```

before deployment of the function to the AWS provider I copy all the files from `customDependencies` to `node_modules` and push this `node_modules` to S3 and create a layer resource where all the lambda functions refers for `node_modules`

example of functions using common code

```
//func1

import {HTTP_STATUS_CODE, stringifyResponse} from "api_response_utils"

/*
api_response_utils is referenced from a lambda layer
*/

export const handler = (ctx) => {
    stringifyResponse(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS,ctx.req.body)

}

//-----------------


//func2

import {HTTP_STATUS_CODE, stringifyResponse} from "api_utils"


export const handler = (ctx) => {
    stringifyResponse(HTTP_STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS,ctx.req.body)

}
```

I am having trouble implementing this for azure environment.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to know if there is any way to replicate the lambda layers concept in azure.

**What I tried**

I tried copying all the files inside `customDependencies/nodejs` to `node_modules` with this `cp -r customDependencies/nodejs/* node_modules` I also have `serverless-webpack` installed as plugin which makes use of this `webpack config` given below.

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require("path");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");


module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal
        ? "source-map"
        : "eval-cheap-module-source-map",


    externals: [nodeExternals()],



    resolve: {
        extensions: [".mjs", ".json", ".ts", ".js"],
        symlinks: false,
        cacheWithContext: false,
    },
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true,
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "commonjs",
        path: path.join(__dirname, ".webpack"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            {
                test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: [
                    [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, ".serverless"),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack"),
                    ],
                ],
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    experimentalWatchApi: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
    ],
};
```

when I try `serverless package` webpack is not able to find custom dependencies

for example I get a warning

`Could not determine version of module api_response_utils.js`

followed by an error

I fixed this error by removing `externals` property from `webpack` config.

this was a workaround I did, the deployment is working fine but I want to know if there are any better approaches to replicate the ***AWS Lambda Layers*** concept to azure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AWS the layers are reusable code that can be utilized by multiple Lambdas (across AWS accounts as well I believe). There are some limits here, max of 5 layers per Lambda and layers should be < 250MB.

In Azure it's a little different, you can deploy multiple functions within a function app and all functions in a function app can use the same packages (shared code).  Code can't be shared across different function apps, that's the key part.  There is no limit on the deployment package.